# Swap Endianness javascript

Tags: javascript, hex, endianness

I'd like to know how to swap the Endianness of a hex value with javascript (ex:  4075 -> 7540, 3827 -> 2738)
If so, how?
Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks @kay, what I want to do is swap the hex's Endianness.

Comment: Your example does not reverse the value...

Comment: Of course it's possible, JavaScript has a perfectly rich `String` type. What's the question?

Comment: 4E20 in hex is 20000 in decimal. So what's your goal? Please explain better.

Comment: Well, dunno if reverse is the right term. I gave two examples of how I want the HEX changed.

Comment: Your examples are not consistent please fix them. Also use `@` to notify when you post comment or edit otherwise those who commented won't get any notification.

Comment: You want 0xABCD to become 0xCDAB, i.e. swap its [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: `@skimberk1`: You hardly encourage useful answers when you fail to put even basic effort into the question. Your examples are all over the place, you haven't backed them with a description of the change...

Comment: @kay Yes, thanks for finding the correct term.

Comment: You still can't be bothered to fix your examples?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Examples updated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To swap the endianness of a number *v*:

```
var v = 0x01234567;                 // input number
var s = v.toString(16);             // translate to hexadecimal notation
s = s.replace(/^(.(..)*)$/, "0$1"); // add a leading zero if needed
var a = s.match(/../g);             // split number in groups of two
a.reverse();                        // reverse the groups
var s2 = a.join("");                // join the groups back together
var v2 = parseInt(s2, 16);          // convert to a number

alert(s2); // "67452301"
alert(v2); // 1732584193
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ohabod/2)

In one long line:

```
alert(parseInt((0x01234567).toString(16).replace(/^(.(..)*)$/, "0$1").match(/../g).reverse().join(""), 16))
```